# How do I parse the following JSON field? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I seem to be unable to parse the following JSON field (named 'attributes') in the normal way:

`select attributes -> 'foo'
from schema.table`

The JSON field has a key-date-value format I've never seen before.

In Postgres, how would I parse this JSON field to select just the value of the barcode? So far, I've had to fallback on string parsing instead, which is unideal.

```
[{"key": "amount", "date": "2019-08-01T13:39:50.823Z", "value": 10}, 
 {"key": "userId", "date": "2019-08-01T13:39:50.823Z", "value": 
  "4e79a15b24174970a913b5c94c030068"},
 {"key": "accountUuid", "date": "2019-08-01T13:39:50.823Z", "value": 
  "bd305700-b461-11e9-8153-adf1629b78f9"},
 {"key": "transactionId", "date": "2019-08-01T13:39:50.823Z", "value": 
  "e04a4099-8038-4cdc-8024-86147f23c749"},
 {"key": "paymentType", "date": "2019-08-01T13:39:50.823Z", "value": 
  "bank_transfer"},
 {"key": "vendor", "date": "2019-08-01T13:39:50.823Z", "value": 
  "12512"},
 {"key": "barcode", "date": "2019-08-01T13:39:50.823Z", "value": 
  "0298350928359829052"},
 {"key": "expirationDate", "date": "2019-08-01T13:39:50.823Z","value": 
  "2019-08-11T00:00:00.000Z"},
 {"key": "date", "date": "2019-08-01T13:39:50.823Z", "value":
  "2019-08-01T13:39:50.823Z"}]
```

Thanks a million!

Comment: What is the output you want?

Comment: I want to output 0298350928359829052, which is the barcode number

Answer (score 1):

You need to unnest the element of the array and then pick the one with the `key = barcode`:

```
select x.j ->> 'value'
from the_table
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(attributes) as x(j)
where x.j ->> 'key' = 'barcode'
```

If you are already using Postgres 12, this is a little bit easier as you can use a [SQL/JSON path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) query

```
select jsonb_path_query_first(attributes, '$[*] ? (@.key == "barcode").value') 
from data
```